# Autodesk forge grey colour showing through colour material

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am trying to simply change the colour of a model in autodesk forge. I am using the following code.

Creation of the material

```
var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial
            ({
                color: new THREE.Color("rgb(255, 0, 0)"),
                transparent: false
            });
```

Adding it to the list of materials

```
materials.addMaterial(
            'NewMaterial',
            material,
            true)
```

Line of code that actually sets the material

```
fragList.setMaterial(fragId, material);
```

This works almost perfectly. The colour of the model changes to red as it should but as you move the view around, what looks like the underlying grey of the model seems to be showing through the red like its clipping through in certain areas.

I have been through https://threejs.org/docs/#api/materials/MeshPhongMaterial and messed with a bunch of properties of the material and while they changed the look of the material especially the lighting properties however nothing would stop the grey clipping through. Any suggestions on what could be causing this or where to look would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if there is a down side to using this method but I used the setThemingColour that was demonstrated in the easter code sample.
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/happy-easter-setthemingcolor-model-material

```
var red = new THREE.Vector4(1, 0, 0, 0.5);
viewer.setThemingColor(dbId, red);
```

Changed the colour, doesnt show through other models like overlays and doesnt have the clipping issue I had.

Answer (score 0):

use this extension from Autodesk forge instead of working on three.js directly.

https://forge.autodesk.com/cloud_and_mobile/2015/12/change-color-of-elements-with-view-and-data-api.html

It is very simple, you just have to write few lines:
`viewer.loadExtension('Autodesk.ADN.Viewing.Extension.Color');
viewer.setColorMaterial([objectIds],colorcodes);`

Comment: I have tried using the extension as well as trying to implement a slightly modified version of it but both times the same thing happens with the colour clipping (albeit not as drastic) but it also introduced another issue. I assume it is because it is using code to add an overlay whatever you change the colour of starts showing through everything else in the model